# Why isn't my ajax call completing, it's sending, but I receive a 404 in response from CakePHP?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I have the following ajax call:

```
$("#welcome a.close").click(function(e) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/visitors/hide_welcome",
        success: function(){
            $("#welcome").hide(0);
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

Aimed at the following piece of my site:

```
<div id="welcome">
    <h2>Welcome  <a class="close" href="Javascript:;"></a></h2>
    <div class="left">
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <div class="loginElement">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

With the following code to answer the ajax request:

```
<?php
class VisitorsController extends AppController {

        function hide_welcome() {
                if($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()) {
                        $this->Session->write('Welcome.hidden', true);
                        echo 'Success.';
                }
                else {
                        echo 'I am, in fact, here.<br>';
                        $this->autoRender = false;
                }
        }

}
?>
```

It's pretty straight forward.  It calls to `/visitors/hide_welcome` to set a session variable noting that they've hidden the welcome.  But it doesn't seem to complete.  If I place alerts on either side of it, like so:

```
$("#welcome a.close").click(function(e) {
    alert("Begin.");
            $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/visitors/hide_welcome",
        success: function(){
            $("#welcome").hide(0);
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
            alert("End.");
});
```

They will trigger.  But alerts placed in `success` are ignored.  The same goes for `error` and `complete`.  This was working just fine on my test machine.  The page in question is definitely there, I can reach it with out ajax.  Firebug reports nothing, neither does the error console.  `Success` simply never fires.

The strangest part is that often if I reload manually the welcome disappears, indicating that the ajax call *did* fire.  It just never returned.  What is going on here?  I'm at wits end.  Any one see any trees I haven't barked up yet?

**SOLUTION:**

CakePHP is supposed to auto detect ajax calls. But in this instance, it wasn't.  As a result it was running the code I had for the Ajax, but then returning a 404 when it failed to find a view.  The solution was to append `$this->autoRender= false;` to the end of the ajax handling controller function.  After that everything worked beautifully.

Comment: What does that `<a>` you're clicking on look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I *think* given your symptoms, you're redirecting to whatever URL the `<a class="close">` you're clicking on pointed to - since the *default* behavior isn't prevented.

The [`e.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) call should happen in the base method, not a callback, like this:

```
$("#welcome a.close").click(function(e) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/visitors/hide_welcome",
        success: function(){
            $("#welcome").hide(0);
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: There's no apparent loading of Firefox, but I suppose its possible that it happens fast enough for me to not notice.  I will attempt this change.

Comment: @Daniel - do you have an example page I can hit?

Comment: http://www.fridgetofood.com  -- It's live.  I've bandaided it by placing the call to hide before the ajax call, which works fine -- more evidence that the ajax is being called and just isn't hitting a complete function for some reason.  I just removed the bandaid, so you may play.

Comment: @Daniel - I get a 404 when accessing the URL via XMLHttpRequest, need to see why your server is blocking an AJAX request to the same path.  Try this in your console - `$.get("/visitors/hide_welcome");`

Comment: @Nick Craver You're looking at the old close welcome, if you look, its commented out.  I'll remove it for good measure, it wouldn't be the first time a browser had ignored my comments o.O  I forgot that was there, honestly.

Comment: @Nick Craver Removing the comment makes no difference.

Comment: @Daniel - No need, I see your current code now...but the AJAX request is failing, your server seems to be handling an AJAX request differently, it *seems* to be checking for the  `X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest` header and giving a 404 for that...a normal XMLHttpRequest without the header still works.  For example try this in the page: `var req = new XMLHttpRequest(); req.open('GET', 'http://www.fridgetofood.com/visitors/hide_welcome', false); req.send(null); if(req.status == 200) console.log(req.responseText);`

Comment: Try adding an `error` callback, and see what kind of data you get.

Comment: Hmm.. that might be a result of CakePHP, I'll edit in the code to the hide_welcome function.

Comment: @Daniel - that part works, in the 404 response you get `Success.` followed by an entire webpage, but it's a 404 response code, not a 200...not familiar with Cake though, so you'll need to both end the response (`die` for example), and set the correct status code.

Comment: @Nick Craver Got it.  The 404 was due to CakePHP failing to find a view for the ajax call.  It is supposed to auto-detect ajax calls and not look for a view in that case.  But for some reason, it wasn't doing that in this case.  Telling it not to worry about the view fixed it, and it started successfully sending the 200 response. Thank you so much for all your help, if I could upvote a dozen times I would.

Comment: You need to tell it to use ajax layout everytime it's ajax request, you can do it in the app_controller::beforeFilter() to make it work across Controllers.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding data to your success callback like so:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/visitors/hide_welcome",
    success: function(data){
        $("#welcome").hide(0);
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

EDIT:
Try supplying the absolute path of your url:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://fridgetofood.com/visitors/hide_welcome",
    success: function(data){
        $("#welcome").hide(0);
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: erm, is this intended? <a class=" close" ...>, line 42 in chrome

Comment: Yes, you may separate classes with spaces, they are ignored.  I'll remove it in any case, just for safeties sake.

Comment: Curious, that space isn't there in my code, and isn't there in the Firefox generated source...

Comment: As nick mentioned, I think it's your server blocking ajax connection? I'm guessing your using CakePHP, you can test for AJAX Request using RequestHandler component, like so: if($this->RequestHandler->isAjax())

Comment: One quick fix is to change success to complete, so regardless of the result you still hide the div. complete: function(data) {

Comment: Got it, it was CakePHP snafu.  Thanks for trying to help though, upvoted :)

Comment: add this in your app_controller::beforeFilter(): if($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()) $this->layout = 'ajax'; a suggestion :p